# Can't serve static content out of Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have a simple Struts2 app that is serving JSP files just fine.  But when I try to serve CSS files, I get `404`.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
            30
      </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In my WEB-INF I have a `content` folder where I serve JSP files (using the convention plugin).  I tried putting a `css\application.css` folder/file in both the `content` and `web-inf` root directly.  Neither work.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I figured it out.  I had the folder in the wrong location.

It needed to be directly in the web folder and not WEB-INF.

Dur...